# How to place CustomView in rightBarButtonItem from Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

[image]Here I created the Navigation controller, and I placed the custom view in the rightbar navigationitem. But the view is not visible with in the navigation bar its exceeded to half of the view

Xcode version: 6.1.1
Using Size classes

Could you any help me please, regarding this custom view placing in the rightbarbutton item

Comment: You can only add the barButtonItem with customView... are you trying to place a customView or cutom barButtonItem?

Comment: I am try only to add the customview to barButtonItem, but i getting the half of the view please refer the screenshot